# Get information about the mentioned user / message author with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

`**• Server Roles:**  <@&${user._roles.join('> <@&')}>`,
^^ Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
I used message.member._roles.join('> <@&')}>`,
But it always showed the roles of the user that wrote the command, and not the user that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message.member is user who sent this message.
If you want to get mentioned guild members you need to use [message.mentions.members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members)
which returns an collection of mentioned users. 
Your code should look like:

```
// To make sure that only one member is mentioned
if(message.mentions.members.size == 1){
    const roles = `<@&${message.mentions.members.first()._roles.join('> <@&')}>`
    message.channel.send(roles);
}
```

I recommend sending empty message first and then editing its content to add these mentions just to avoid pinging whole server.

Comment: (node:9764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_roles' of undefined

Comment: 1. Did you use exactly my code?
2. Did you check size of message.mentions.members before joining _roles array?
3. Do you use the newest version od discord.js? (12.2.0)
You can check it using *npm list* command

Comment: My command is supposed to show the roles in a bigger command (user-info) i need only to manage to show tagged's user's roles or either the message's author's ones.

Comment: And this error appears even when you mention someone? And if possible could you answer my questions from comment above?

Comment: I want it to work also for message.author though :(

Comment: Yeah it works for mentions now, but I want to do it for message.author too.

Comment: Message.author represents Discord User, message.member represents Guild Member. So use message.member instead because you cannot get roles from message.author (make sure that message.member !== null)

Comment: So basically in my code i have this now
if(message.mentions.members.size == 1)
        const roles = `<@&${message.mentions.members.first()._roles.join('> <@&')}>`
and above this all i have defined user as
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
where/what should i do with message.member !== null

Comment: message.member can be null only if command is not executed on Discord Server. So you can just add check if message is written on the guild i.e. ```if(message.channel.type == "dm") return``` and then you don't need to check if message.member !== null

Comment: It's for discord server, the command is also user-info

Comment: I want it to do the same thing as the mention way, but if an user is not mentioned, show stats ( a.k.a roles ) for the message author